# sql query result from executenonquery to text file vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, output, executenonquery

Please see the following Code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO


Public Class frm_main

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sqlFile As String = "ExecOnServer.sql"
        Dim sqlText = File.ReadAllText(sqlFile)
        Dim connStr = "Server=MyServer; Database=MyServer; Integrated Security=SSPI"
        Dim conn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim str_result_int As Integer
        Dim str_result As String
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, conn)

        Try
            conn.Open()
            File.AppendAllText("ExecOnServer.txt", vbCrLf & DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") & "...Opening Connection..." & vbCrLf)
            str_result_int = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If str_result_int >= 1 Then
                str_result = "Executed Successfully!!"
            Else
                str_result = "Executed But No Rows were Affected!!"
            End If
            File.AppendAllText("ExecOnServer.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") & "...Executing Query..." & vbCrLf)
            File.AppendAllText("ExecOnServer.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") & " " & str_result & vbCrLf)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("Something went wrong: " & ex.Message)
            File.AppendAllText("ExecOnServer.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") & "...Something went wrong: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
        Finally
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
                File.AppendAllText("ExecOnServer.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") & "...Done!" & vbCrLf)
                'MsgBox("Done")
            End If
            Me.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is working perfectly fine!! The issue is that the output file (ExecOnServer.txt) that is being appended needs to include the Messages of the query executed in ExecOnServer.sql. By Messages, I mean "(1 row(s) affected)" or "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid object name 'User_Tax_Rates'.". The variable "str_result" can be used or a new variable can be created.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the numbers of affected rows

```
        If str_result_int >= 1 Then
            str_result = "Executed Successfully!!"
            MessageBox(str_result_int & " row(s) affected")
        Else
```

and the error message you can cahtch from ex.Message .. or put a brekpoint and see what property has that message in ex.